# Changing the font size inside \pgfmathprintnumber

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I'm using tikz to draw some rectangels and square. I want to write an index near each such element and I want the font size to be \tiny. Where should I put the \tiny command?

```
node[anchor=south,text=red] {
  \pgfmathparse{8*\m+\v}
  \tiny\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}
}
```

didn't worked..
This is my working code (with default font size):

```
\begin{document}

\tikzset{addition/.style={draw,circle,append after command={
        [shorten >=\pgflinewidth, shorten <=\pgflinewidth,]
        (\tikzlastnode.north) edge (\tikzlastnode.south)
        (\tikzlastnode.east) edge (\tikzlastnode.west)
        }
    }
}
\tikzset{line/.style={draw, -latex',shorten <=1bp,shorten >=1bp}}

\tikzstyle{block}=[draw, rectangle, minimum size=2em]
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto]

\foreach \m in {0,1,2}{
    \foreach \v in {0,1,...,7}{
        \draw [red] plot [only marks, mark size=2.5, mark=*] coordinates {(2*\m, -\v)} 
        node[anchor=south,text=red] {
             \pgfmathparse{8*\m+\v}
             \pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}
        };
    }
    \foreach \v in {0,1,...,7}{
        \draw [blue] plot [only marks, mark=square*] coordinates {(2*\m + 1,-\v)}
        node[anchor=south,text=blue] {
            \pgfmathparse{8*\m+\v}
            \pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}
        };
    }
}
\foreach \v in {0,1,...,7}{
    \draw [red] plot [only marks, mark size=2.5, mark=*] coordinates {(2*3, -\v)}
        node[anchor=south,text=red] {
        \pgfmathparse{8*3+\v}
        \pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}
    };
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Try adding `font=\tiny` to the `node` options.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please don't post code fragments. Instead, put your fragments into a complete compilable  document that shows the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you should always post compilable fragment, because your assertion that the first snippet doesn't work seems false. See:

```latex
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,positioning,calc}
\begin{document}
\def\m{3}\def\v{4}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \path (0,0) node[anchor=south,text=red] {
  \pgfmathparse{8*\m+\v}
  \tiny\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}
  } 
  (1,0) node[anchor=south,text=red] {
    \pgfmathparse{8*\m+\v}
    \pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

produces:

[image]

Anyway, the best way in my opinion is this:

```latex
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,positioning,calc}
\begin{document}
\def\m{3}\def\v{4}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    my red node/.style={
        anchor=south, text=red, font=\tiny
    }]
  \path
  (0,0) node[my red node] {
  \pgfmathparse{8*\m+\v}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}} 
  (1,0) node[my red node] {
      \pgfmathparse{8*\m+\v}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}}
  ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use `font=\tiny` in your node option.

Or if you want every node to display its content in tiny font, then use `every node/.style={font=\tiny}` in your `tikzpicture` option.